# Accidentally clipped into Shimano PD-A530 BACKWARDS -- won't release!

Tags: shimano, clipless, cleat, pedals-clipless

OK, I'll bet I'm the first person to do this boneheaded move: while waiting for a pedal wrench to remove old pedals and install new Shimano PD-A530, someone asked me to demonstrate how the shoe clips into the pedal.  Making sure I grabbed a right foot shoe and the right side pedal, a proceeded to demonstrate -- without realizing I had the pedal 180 degrees in the wrong orientation. After pushing harder than usual, it clipped in -- but it absolutely won't clip out!

Not sure if it makes it worse that my cleats are SM-SH56 "multi-release" cleats.  I really don't see how I can get them to release.  Any expert insight?

Pedals
[image]

Cleats
[image]

Comment: Have you tried clipping out in the opposite direction from normal? Though I don't see why it'd make a difference from clipping out as normal. But I use Look, so...

Comment: Do you have access to the spring tension / release tension adjust?  Could you slack the tension?

Comment: @batman I've tried clipping out in every direction. So far no luck.

Comment: @Criggie the spring was already set at the lowest tension. I'm not sure if I can "pry" the spring back a little bit.

Comment: Could you get a tool past the pedal axle to the two bolts on the cleat?  If the shoe was not in the way then it would be a lot easier to exert force on the pedal clips.

Comment: @Batman even though they don't say so, SPDs (even the not multi-release ones) release perfectly well by pushing your heel *in* (so long as you don't kick the crank). They're symmetrical. So while trying twisting in every direction is a good idea, *opposite* doesn't really mean much.

Comment: I understand that the pedal isn't mounted. In my experience it is very difficult to unclip by hand. May not look so, but legs/feet exert more power. You may want to try with the pedal in a vice or when it'll be bolted to your crank.

Answer (score 3):

You are right that  these cleats are "multi-release" which should help.

So try twisting the shoe straight up, but given the cleats are backwards you may need to lift/rotate the TOE end of the shoe not the HEEL end.

[image]

Good luck!

Comment: On those pedals it looks like you could get a makeshift pry bar under the moving part at the same time as lifting the toe.

Comment: @ChrisH -- SUCCESS!  This turned out to be the right solution. I placed the blade of a large flathead screwdriver directly beneath the area of the spring (where the hex adjustment screw is located) and rotated. This instantly released the cleat!  Thanks. (If you enter an Answer, I can mark it as correct)

Answer (score 1):

On some pedal designs such as these, you may be able to get a screwdriver or similar improvised pry bar under the moving part of the clip.  This should free it up, but you might need to twist the shoe, pull the toe up at the same time.